# Check if a GPS location is within a certain radius of another GPS location in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm developing an Android app which takes the user's current location and shows other users' gps locations on a map which falls with a certain radius, say 20 kilometers.

For example, if I am the user, I want to see other users' locations plotted on a map who are within a radius of 20 kilometers from my location.

I am able to save my location, other users' locations and plot them on map also. I am not able to figure out if those users fall in 20 kilometers radius from my location or not.

I use ***Google Maps Android API v2*** to plot locations on map and ***Parse*** for saving the GPS locations (latitude and longitude coordinates)

I Googled for solutions but in vain. Could anyone please provide a hint or reference or sample code on how to check if a GPS location is within a certain radius of another GPS location or not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very easy. When you add Marker into your Map just get distance from that Marker to your Current Location if distance is <= 20 then add that marker into Map. Like so

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(oldPosition.latitude, oldPosition.longitude,
            newPosition.latitude, newPosition.longitude, results);
```

Comment: What is **results** used for? Can you just explain.

Comment: @athi09 results variable contains distance.

Comment: why is it _float[1]_ ?

Comment: @athi09 Just and array with two elements

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093792/android-google-map-find-distance-between/22093862#22093862](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093792/android-google-map-find-distance-between/22093862#22093862)

Comment: Thank you **M D**. I'll just try this out and let you know the result

Comment: I'm getting some value. Is the _results_ shown in meters?

Comment: @athi09 you should be able to find out yourself what value distancebetween delivers. Since it is an API function, just read the online docu.

Comment: distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them.

Answer (score 1):

First get distance between 2 position:

```
float[] distance = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(oldPosition.latitude, oldPosition.longitude,
        currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude, distance);
```

distance will be in meter.

So, we have to convert our designer radius (20 KM) distance in meter to compare.

```
double radiusInMeters = 20.0*1000.0; //1 KM = 1000 Meter
```

New we can check that current position is inside 20 KM radius or not using...

```
if( distance[0] > radiusInMeters ){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
    "Outside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " radius: " + radiusInMeters, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
    "Inside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " radius: " + radiusInMeters , 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Enamul but I already got the answer and I have accepted it too.